# FEM for PDE on curves: describing interpolation inequality

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

in page 312 Lemma 4.3 (interpolation) of the monograph
[Finite element methods for surface PDEs](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/staff/C.M.Elliott/DziEll13a.pdf)
is stated as follows:\
for $n \leq 3$ and given $\eta \in H^2(\Gamma)$ (where $\Gamma$ is a surface) there exists a unique $I_h \eta \in S^l_h$ such that:
$$ \|\eta - I_h \eta\|_{L^2(\Gamma)} +h\|\nabla_{\Gamma}(\eta - I_h \eta)\|_{L^2(\Gamma)} \leq ch^2\big(\|\nabla_{\Gamma}^2\eta \|_{L^2(\Gamma)} + h \|\nabla_{\Gamma}\eta \|_{L^2(\Gamma)} \big), $$ 
then later in page 322 by this equation, from 
$$1/2 \|\nabla_{\Gamma}(u_h-\varphi_h)\|_{L^2(\Gamma)} \leq \|\nabla_{\Gamma}(u-\varphi_h)\|_{L^2(\Gamma)} + ch^2\|\nabla_{\Gamma}\varphi_h \|_{L^2(\Gamma)} + A,$$
and replacing $\varphi_h = I_h u$ the following inequality is derived:
$$1/2 \|\nabla_{\Gamma}(u_h-I_h u)\|_{L^2(\Gamma)} \leq (1+ch^2) \|\nabla_{\Gamma}(u-I_h u)\|_{L^2(\Gamma)} + ch^2\|\nabla_{\Gamma}u \|_{L^2(\Gamma)} + A,$$
is derived. I do not understand how they reached to the last inequality.\

I'll appreciate if anyone help me to figure this out. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is just a typo, clearly there is an error since the orders differ from the first estimate, but notice that $$(1+ch^2)\le (1+ch),$$
Which I believe is the right estimate, based upon the given inequality.